# Parameter #1 $object of method expects x given y - abstract entities

Tags: phpstan

I have a abstract class User:

```php
abstract class User
```

and a child of User, "Administrator":

```php
class Administrator extends User
```

When i create a new Administrator and want to persist with this signature:

```php
public function persist(Administrator $object): void
```

```php
$this->repo->persist(new Administrator())
```

PHPSTAN is complaining:

Parameter #1 $object of method AdministratorRepository::persist() expects Administrator, User given

Why it thinks it's User where i am instantiating an new Administrator directly?
I think its about Covariance and Contravariance but cant figure out how to tell PHPSTAN correctly?

I checked the https://phpstan.org/blog/whats-up-with-template-covariant but did not get a solution to work properly.

Comment: With a code like `$this->repo->persist(new Administrator())`, PHPStan will definitely not complain about `Parameter #1 $object of method AdministratorRepository::persist() expects Administrator, User given`. Please reproduce your problem on phpstan.org/try, and ask about this in GitHub Discussions in PHPStan repository. Thanks.

Comment: My return type of the abstract User was self instead of static - my fault!